# firefox odd padding using anchor tags

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to make an achor tag button by adding a background, and while it looks fine in chrome and safari, firefox 15.0.1 seems to have a bug.

For example, http://jsfiddle.net/cqVjj/3/ shows that the text is not even vertically centered. I didn't even specify padding, width, or height, but I expect similar results as chrome. Firefox I see a space at the bottom.

Any solutions?

chrome 21.0.1
[image: chrome]

firefox 15.0.1
[image: firefox]

Comment: Looks the same to me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Looks same to me in both browsers..

Comment: check out the added images. It doesn't appear like that in your firefox 15.0.1 browser. I'm on osx too if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix:

You are missing the `line-height` attribute. It has to be the same value as the `font-size`:

`line-height: 34px;`

I updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqVjj/4/

Comment: well it makes both browser consistent, but it still has more space at the bottom than at the top. I'll post pictures to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

This is not consistent through browsers. I suggest you balance spacing with padding. See example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/exzRT/

Strangely enough changing the font to a sans-serif font like 'Arial' helps.

Comment: I'm using helvetica, which seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

The rendering will depend on the exact fonts the browsers are using and on the exact ascent and descent metrics they decide to use for those fonts.  Note that you're not even telling them to use the same font family in your fiddle.

But even past that, what CSS2.1 has to say on the matter is (from http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced ):

```
The height of the content area should be based on the font, but this
specification does not specify how. A UA may, e.g., use the em-box or
the maximum ascender and descender of the font.
```

I suspect that the browsers you're looking at are in fact just using different definitions of the content area of the inline.